# Biblatex, uniquename, \ifnamesequal{editor}{author}

Tags: biblatex, biber

As soon as one uses `biblatex` with biber as backend and  `uniquename=true` enabled, the test `\ifnamesequal{editor}{author}` inside the bbx-file (here: `authortitle-dw.bbx`) won't expand to true even if the fields `{editor}` and `{author}` are identical in the bib-file. This is because  `uniquename` adds a value to the namelist `labelname` (= `author`) so that `\ifnamesequal{editor}{author}` expands to false in any case. Compare following example with `uniquename=true` and `uniquename=false`. In the first case, the output of the editor is "Zeller" and in the second case "ders". Is there a way to get "ders" even with `uniquename=true`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,uniquename=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Zeller1988,
Address = {G{\"o}ttingen},
Author = {Dieter Zeller},
Booktitle = {Menschwerdung Gottes -- Verg{\"o}ttlichung von Menschen},
Editor = {Dieter Zeller},
Number = {7},
Pages = {141-176},
Series = {NTOA},
Shorttitle = {Menschwerdung},
Title = {Die Menschwerdung des Sohnes Gottes im Neuen Testament und die antike Religionsgeschichte},
Year = {1988}}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\cite[]{Zeller1988}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a [bug](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=1126005&aid=3390856&group_id=244752) in biblatex which has already been reported and should be fixed with the next release which is due soon.